# Indicate remote files in mode-line

Tags: tramp, mode-line

Does anybody know how to clearly indicate in the mode-line that I'm working on a remote file (e.g. with the color of the buffer name, model-line background or some small tag).

I use `tramp` to work remotely and my mode line is customized with `powerline`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is already a small indication `@` in the modeline, when you're remote. Move the mouse over this char, and you'll see the remote path as hint.

If you need more: try `tramp-theme` from GNU ELPA. It is intended for exactly this purpose.
Warning: I am the author of that package :-)

Comment: Weirdly I do have @ when swithching buffers with helm, but not in modeline... I wonder if it is a powerline bug/quirk. I'll have a look at the tramp-theme you suggested. Thanks.